# jQuery - Replace content of td with predefined element

Tags: jquery

Is there any function that would act like `.appendTo()`, but would replace content instead of appending, keeping replacer as an jQuery object? The `html()` does not keep element as object, simply converts it to html.

The problem is that I would like to be able to dynamically edit table cells. So when user hovers td, a button with pencil appears, and after clicking on it, cell content is put into input box, and replaced with that input.

Procedure is easy, but this is annoying that switching to input reduces cell size, so whole table is being resized. Using `html()` fixes that, but it ruins `blur` event as well as autofocusing or selecting text in input box.

It's something like this:

```
<script>
    var parent = $(this).parent();
    var old = $(parent).html();
    var input = $('<input type="text"/>').val($(parent).text()).attr('rel',old);

    //--- would like to combine lines below ---//

    $(parent).html(''); <-- this resizes table cell
    $(input).appendTo($(parent)).focus().select(); //<-- this is important thing.
</script>
```

Input width is set to 100%.

If I use `$(parent).html($(input).focus().select());` it of course won't resize table cell, but does not focus or select text neither, because the node is not yet in document.

Adding input first and then removing old content is a bad idea, as it extends table cell size.

**Please don't even mention about `replaceWidth()` as it is not what I mean!**

Table cell is mentioned to be as small as possible, so:

```
td{
   width:1px;
   padding:5px;
   white-space:nowrap;
}
```

as max-width does not work with table cells with `nowrap`, the content is put into the div that limits size of the content to 150px:

```
.td_limiter{
   max-width:150px;
   overflow:hidden;
   text-overflow:ellipsis;
}
```

Comment: did you try the .replace() function ?

Comment: there is no such a function in `jQuery`

Comment: maybe .replaceWith() ?

Comment: Try `$(input).appendTo($(parent).empty()).focus().select()`

Comment: I ment replaceAll() which replaces source and contents reversed

Comment: @WannaCSharp Please read last line of my question - the bold one. `replaceWidth()` does not replace inner node content. It replaces whole node - so sizes are not being kept at all.

Comment: @Emin `replaceAll()` replaces all parent nodes, so for every node new input appears.

Comment: @ArunPJohny: resize event is still being shot. That is too bad... maybe there is no way to do this without some weird cell / input manipulation, or visibility changes...

Comment: Wow another person gave `-1` without even reading the thread. How nice.

Comment: can you also send the HTML for your table. may be a css trick will stop it being resized?

Comment: I balanced that with an upvote :)

Comment: @Emin: I've edited question, added css.

Comment: One last thing.. Did you try .on method for binding events to dynamically created elements?

Comment: I am using `.on()` events. But the problem is totally visual... while replacing content of cell, it has no data for a moment and whole column is being resized to next biggest element

Comment: Ok so the problem is totally out of the jquery subject but a css issue. As far as I understand the functionality works fine however as for the visual interaction, you have problems. Please correct if I am wrong. My suggestion is to re-think your css classes also, in your .td_limiter define a standard width. dont forget that max-width ovverrides the width property. So for that little moment, you're getting width 100% until max width..

Comment: Hmm... I need to keep the table as narrow as it can be. There are lots of pages where some fields empty, and keeping space for empty fields is not what I would like to do. The option would be to make input position absolute and simply cover the content that is under. But it can't be done that way, because `IE9` is messing up `border-collapse` when table cell position is set to relative... I hate it, but I got to write an IE9 compatible app.